# How to specify a variable in pandas as ordinal/categorical?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, categorical-data, nominal-data

I am trying to run some Machine learning algo on a dataset using scikit-learn. My dataset has some features which are like categories. Like one feature is `A`, which has values `1,2,3` specifying the quality of something. `1:Upper, 2: Second, 3: Third class`. So it's an ordinal variable.

Similarly I re-coded a variable `City`, having three values `('London', Zurich', 'New York'` into `1,2,3` but with no specific preference for the values. So now this is a nominal categorical variable.

How do I specify the algorithm to consider these as categorical and ordinal etc. in pandas?. Like in R, a categorical variable is specified by `factor(a)` and hence is not considered a continuous value. Is there anything like that in pandas/python?

Answer (score 38):

... years later (and because I think a good explanation of these issues is required not only for this question but to help remind myself in the future)

### Ordinal vs. Nominal

In general, one would translate categorical variables into dummy variables (or a [host of other methodologies](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/library/r-library-contrast-coding-systems-for-categorical-variables)), **because** they were nominal, e.g. they had **no** sense of  `a > b > c` . In OPs original question, this would **only** be performed on the Cities, like London, Zurich, New York.

#### Dummy Variables for Nominal

For this type of issue, `pandas` provides -- by far -- the easiest transformation using [`pandas.get_dummies`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29289903/963989). So:

```
# create a sample of OPs unique values
series = pandas.Series(
           numpy.random.randint(low=0, high=3, size=100))
mapper = {0: 'New York', 1: 'London', 2: 'Zurich'}
nomvar = series.replace(mapper)

# now let's use pandas.get_dummies
print(
    pandas.get_dummies(series.replace(mpr))

Out[57]:
    London  New York  Zurich
0        0         0       1
1        0         1       0
2        0         1       0
3        1         0       0
```

#### Ordinal Encoding for Categorical Variables

However in the case of ordinal variables, the user must be cautious in using [`pandas.factorize`](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.factorize.html). The reason is that the engineer wants to preserve the relationship in the mapping such that  `a > b > c`.

So if I want to take a set of categorical variables where `large > medium > small`, and preserve that, I need to make sure that `pandas.factorize` preserves that relationship.

```
# leveraging the variables already created above
mapper = {0: 'small', 1: 'medium', 2: 'large'}
ordvar = series.replace(mapper)

print(pandas.factorize(ordvar))

Out[58]:
(array([0, 1, 1, 2, 1,...  0, 0]),
Index(['large', 'small', 'medium'], dtype='object'))
```

In fact, the relationship that **needs to be preserved in order to maintain the concept of ordinal** has been lost using `pandas.factorize`. In an instance like this, I use my own mappings to ensure that the ordinal attributes are preserved.

```
preserved_mapper = {'large':2 , 'medium': 1, 'small': 0}
ordvar.replace(preserved_mapper)
print(ordvar.replace(preserved_mapper))

Out[78]:
0     2
1     0
...
99    2
dtype: int64
```

In fact, by creating your own `dict` to map the values is a way to not only preserve your desired ordinal relationship but also can be used as "keeping the contents and mappings of your prediction algorithm organized" ensuring that not only have you not lost any ordinal information in the process, but also have stored records of what each mapping for each variable is.

### `int`s into `sklearn`

Lastly, the OP spoke about passing the information into `scikit-lean` classifiers, which means that `int`s are required. For that case, make sure you're aware of the [`astype(int)` gotcha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287624/pandas-dataframe-column-type-conversion) that is detailed [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na) if you have any `NaN`s in your data.

Comment: I know this is old. But do you one hot encode variables that you believe are ordinal?

Comment: No capacity to write a full answer at the moment, and this answer also provides a lot of context. Current pandas (Mar 2022 now) explicitly has an appropriate type for this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Answer (score 1):

See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html
and see this question [How to reformat categorical Pandas variables for Sci-kit Learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29288041/how-to-reformat-categorical-pandas-variables-for-sci-kit-learn)

Comment: It's better to flesh out your answer rather than post links

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [OneHotEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html) transformer with the categorical variables, and leave the ordinal variable untouched:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'quality': [1, 2, 3], 'city': [3, 2, 1], columns=['quality', 'city']}
>>> enc = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[False, True])
>>> X = df.values
>>> enc.fit(X)
>>> enc.transform(X).todense()
matrix([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
        [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  2.],
        [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  3.]])
```

Comment: Hi , I have tried that in the past.  So does this method encodes all categorical variable which we specify as dummy variable right? Is there a way to keep sense of order? Like for quality variable 1,2,3 does make some sense with respect to kind of quality

Comment: OneHotEncoder lets you specify a subset of vars (array cols) to dummify in the categorical_features argument. This way you can leave the ordinal variable untouched and keep the sense of order.

Comment: but if you leave the ordinals untoruched you did not accomplish anything either...